# My API is not receiving my access token on axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm using this code

```
const { status, data } = await axios({
    method,
    url,
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': userInfo.locale,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token.accessToken.jwtToken}`,
    },
    data: {
      requesterSubscription: token.accessToken.payload.sub,
      ...body,
    },
  });
```

But when I print what I'm receiving on the headers on the API I get:

```
  host: 'XXX.X.X.X:XXXX',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  accept: '*/*',
  'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization,content-type',
  'access-control-request-private-network': 'true',
  origin: 'http://XXX.XXX.XX.X:XXXXX',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://XXX.XXX.XX.X:XXXXX/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,la;q=0.5'
```

So it isn't receiving my authorization and I'm getting errors because of it, there are no other possible places it could be making this request from.

Comment: looks like you are using cross origin - is that the `OPTIONS` request that you see?

Comment: @DanielA.White how can I check that?

Comment: inspect the web browser, go to network section and share us the details when you click something and the request goes to your api. https://curlconverter.com/images/chrome.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1mMi.png

Comment: check where on the server you got the headers from. it should tell you if its the options verb or not

Answer (score -1):

So First (1) question: Where do you store your access token?

- In memory
- In storage (localStorage or sessionStorage). Bad practices
  Second (2) question: Do your retrieve data has `requesterSubscription` key?
  Third : I hope your passing the the `url` and the `method` values?

**Solution:**
I really recommend you to read axios [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro).
Also, it is better to create an export a `axiosInstance` (with a base config. [Docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance)), append interceptors on it for process before and after request.
Tips:

- With the interceptors you can automatically append the token in the request header of your created instance (so you wont have to do it for further request).
- Also check for your `access token` expiration and automatically ask for a new access token with a valid stored `refresh token`
- Do not forget to configure CORS on your API server.

Comment: 1 In memory (context)
2 Yes
3 Yes, in another place (it does only that so the problem couldn't be there)

Comment: Isn't exporting an instance basically what I'm doing here?

Comment: So if it's in memory and you do refresh your page (with React,...) then you lose your access token (that is the point of having a refesh token). If not maybe you misconfigured your request (Check the request in your browser Network tab [Dev tools])

Comment: No you're making a request to `url` with a `method`. And then destructing the response in {status, data}. Read the doc.